Modify system prompt for ReAct agent (langchain)
I have a React agent and I use a prompt from the langsmith hub.
I want to modify the system prompt so that the llm stays within the scope (I am implementing a groceries assistant), so I want to state something like "You are an assistant for an app ..."
Can I modify the prompt from the hub or what could I try?
This is my code
# ReAct agent prompt
    prompt = hub.pull("hwchase17/structured-chat-agent")

    # ConversationBufferMemory stores the conversation history in RAM
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True, k=10)    # return_messages: return list, k: keep last k messages in memory

    # add messages to memory
    for message in chat_history.get_messages(formatted=True):
        memory.chat_memory.add_message(message)

    agent = create_structured_chat_agent(llm=llm, tools=tools, prompt=prompt)

    agent_executor = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
        agent=agent,
        tools=tools,
        verbose=True,
        memory=memory,
        handle_parsing_errors=True,  # handle any parsing errors gracefully

    )

One idea is to copy the prompt and modify it?
Also, will an additional instruction at the beginning influence the reasoning abilities?
